# socket hang up error on request module in nodejs although CURL does correctly

Tags: node.js, sockets, request

I use an API with notable timeout to response and I always faced `Error: socket hang up`
 on `request` module in `nodejs` it's happened although I could CURL url without any problem.
I tried to increase the `timeout` in request options but nothing good happened.
Is there something else instead of timeout?
Should I use other packages instead of `request`?

the `nodejs` code:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { 
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://someapiurl.com/api/search',
  qs: { q: 'Vanak sq' },
  timeout: 12000,
  time: true
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(body);
});
```

the error:

```
Error: Error: socket hang up
    at Request._callback (/home/mohammad/Desktop/test.js:14:20)
    at self.callback (/home/mohammad/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (/home/mohammad/node_modules/request/request.js:884:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:345:9)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
```